# Read a specific cell from a specific worksheet of multiple Excel files in a folder

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, directory

I save a copy of an Excel file in a folder every day. Now, I have 300 files accumulated over time, and I want to plot the development of different cells over time. Some columns may have shifted over time because new ones were added. Therefore, I want to start with a simple approach and tell Python which worksheet the cell is in (as a number) and the cell's number within the worksheet. While I have stored the date and time in the file name, for simplicity, I want to initially use the file's modification date since it matches. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with this, and maybe someone can help me

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


verzeichnis_pfad = r'C:\Users\xxx'

dataframes = []


for datei in os.listdir(verzeichnis_pfad):
    if datei.endswith('.xlsx'):
        datei_pfad = os.path.join(verzeichnis_pfad, datei)

        # X-Value from file options
        timestamp = os.path.getmtime(datei_pfad)
        x_wert = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

        # 7th Worksheet
        df = pd.read_excel(datei_pfad, sheet_name=6)

        # row 3 and column 28 in 7th Worksheet
        y_wert = df.iat[2, 27]  

    
        dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame({'X': [x_wert], 'Y': [y_wert]}))


gesamter_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

#sort data
gesamter_dataframe = gesamter_dataframe.sort_values(by='X')

#plot
plt.plot(gesamter_dataframe['X'], gesamter_dataframe['Y'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Y-Value')
plt.show()
```

I trieds to extract the cell data to my dataframe

Comment: Pls. describe the `trouble` more detailed. Where, what, expected result, got result etc. to get a faster and more concrete answer.